# Getting MySQL-Error "unknown column" but the column exists

Tags: php, mysql, sql, error-handling

the searchfunction did'nt help me..
My MySQL-Query looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = flo;
```

and I get this error:

```
Unknown column 'flo' in 'where clause'
```

But why?
My database does have the table "user", containing multible columns,
one column is named "username".

I also have 2 Test-Users, one of their usernames is "flo" so what is wrong?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Quote it `WHERE username = 'flo'` it's a string and not an integer.

Comment: Please read carefully

Comment: @Fred-ii- thanks! I was just blind seeing this since i was working on other scripts for hours before :-)

Comment: @FlorianChrometz You're welcome. I take it the issue has been solved?

Comment: @FlorianChrometz I have posted an answer for you below to explain it a bit more, and to close the question Florian. *Cheers*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you are getting that error message Florian, is because the word `flo` needs to be wrapped inside quotes.

```
SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = 'flo';
```

In SQL, doing `WHERE column = column` is valid syntax, but in your case, you are wanting to see if `column = (contains) string`.

Comment: Thanks it worked very well! - Also that's a very nooby misstake but the day I asked this wasn't my best day :-)

Comment: @FlorianChrometz You're welcome Florian, glad to have helped, *cheers*